# Where is the business logic in MVP design pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, mvp

I am trying to understand how the MVP pattern works using a simple example.

I want to show the box content when the user clicks a button.

```js
function reveal(number){
  let content;
  if(number==1) content = "candy"
  else if(number==2) content = "chicken"
  else content = "pencil"
  document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "It's a " + content
}
```

```html
<button onclick="reveal(1)"> box 1</button>
<button onclick="reveal(2)"> box 2</button>
<button onclick="reveal(3)"> box 3</button><br>
<h3 id="box"> </h3>
```

YES, I do know it is not the best idea to use such a complicated pattern for this snippet code. I just think this example would be really easy to understand.

Now my questions:

1. Should I put the logic (if...elseif..) in the presenter or in the model?
2. For Question 1, If I put the logic in the presenter, does that mean that the model will be useless?

Answer (score -1):

IMO it should go in the view, there is no need to go to the server and have to wait for a response, the data can all be loaded instantly when the user makes the selection.

the MVP pattern consists of

EventHandling = Presenter

DOM Manipulation = View

AJAX calls = Model

What you have shown is a clip of HTML and a small bit of the corresponding javascript, that together manipulate the DOM. It could be argued that the javascript part handles the event caused by the users selection and put it in the Presenter part of MVP

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the MVP pattern entirely. There's no requirement for *any* part of it to be server side. And business logic definitely does not belong in the view portion of the code.